# User account creation date time?

Tags: macos, user-account

I am using a shared mac in which a new user account was created by another user.  I want to know the dateTime of the account creation.  Is there a way to find it out without asking the peer?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A quick way to do it would be to go to the directory

```
/Users
```

And add the Date Created option via the View Options

[image: view options]

This assumes that the home directory was created at the same time of account itself

Answer (score 0):

Try also this in a Terminal:

```
ls -l ~/*/.localized
```

These files are usually created when the account is created.